# breaking down jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does jQuery protect overwriting jQuery and $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465940/how-does-jquery-protect-overwriting-jquery-and)

I am looking over jQuery source code and there are several lines of code which I don't get.

```
// Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
_jQuery = window.jQuery,

// Map over the $ in case of overwrite
_$ = window.$,
```

My question is what is the code above doing?  How does it work?  I imagine that it is responsible for the jQuery and $ objects, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the sourcecode of the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function you will see this

```
if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
    window.$ = _$;
}
if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
    window.jQuery = _jQuery;
}
```

When Jquery load, it overwrite global `$` and `jQuery`. `noConflict` return these global variables to its former value from backups. These backups were create with the code you mentioned.

Comment: Doh. It's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

That is used in the context of the jQuery function to:

1) Prevents client code from overriding the functionality of `jQuery` and `$` functions.

2) Alias the `jQuery` and `$` functions to [increase speed](http://jsfiddle.net/7EAQb/).

Answer (score 0):

Many libraries using javascript use $.  It is resetting the $ so that other libraries like 
Prototype can use $ without causing conflict errors.  If that wasn't done, the code could not work and could cause errors.